# Catch-all verbs function for Razor Page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

For Razor Pages using ASP.NET Core is there any way to create a catch-all handler for all verbs instead of having separate OnGet(), OnPost(). The handler will need access to HttpContext and Request objects (not provided in the constructor)

Instead of

```
public class ExampleModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
        //do something
    }

    public void OnPost()
    {
        //do something
    }        
}
```

Something like the following

```
public class ExampleModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnAll()
    {
        //code executes for POST, PUT, GET, ... VERBS
    }
}
```

Also would work is just something generic that would execute before or after (with context) each request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also would work is just something generic that would execute before or after (with context) each request

Taking the above into account you probably want to use filters. Declaration:

```
public class DefaultFilterAttribute : ResultFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here we go");

        base.OnResultExecuted(context);
    }
}
```

In case you want to see this behavior on a single page only:

```
[DefaultFilter]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
}
```

In case you need this filter to be applied on all pages (`Startup.cs`):

```
 services.AddMvcOptions(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(typeof(DefaultFilterAttribute));
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a group of commands for all request methods, you can use the constractor of the PageModel:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public IndexModel()
    {
        // This will be executed first
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
}
```

**New solution**

I have an other solution for you. Create a class which will inherit from PageModel where you will catch all the different request methods and call a new virtual method.

```
public class MyPageModel : PageModel
{
    public virtual void OnAll()
    {

    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        OnAll();
    }
    public void OnPost()
    {
        OnAll();
    }
}
```

Now change your PageModel class so that it will inherit from the new class that you created. In your class you can overrice the OnAll method in order to execute your common code.

```
public class TestModel : MyPageModel
{
    public override void OnAll()
    {
        // Write your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: The handler will need access to HttpContext and Request objects (not available in the constructor). I added some clarification to the question.

Comment: Then you will have to add methods for all verbs. All these methods will call a method which will contain tha common code that you want to execute.

Comment: I changed my answer. I added a new solution.